# Apache NiFi - How to add/pass attributes to a Processor, not a flow file

Tags: apache-nifi

## My Purpose

Execute a sql and write result(flow file) using **my own schema** to a file **directly**.

Please see the explanation blow.

---

## Solution 1 (use 4 processors)

1. `ExecuteSql` and the records has auto-generated(embedded) avro schema.
2. `ConvertRecord`: The Record Reader just use embedded avro schema and the Record Writer use my own schema from HortonworkSchemaRegistry, so pass attributes - 'schema.name' and 'schema.version' - by using `UpdateAttribute`.
3. It works.

[image]

## Solution 2 (use `ExecuteSqlRecord`)

It **may** like this:

[image]

`ExecuteSqlRecord` has Record Writer

[image]

And the Record Writer get avro schema from HortonworkSchemaRegistry using 'schema.name' and 'schema.version' attributes

[image]

But `ExecuteSqlRecord` not support user-define-attributes

[image]

---

## So

- Is it the way to use `ExecuteSqlRecord` processor?
- How to add attributes to a processor?

Comment: attributes belongs to a flowfile. just set required attribute for the flowfile before ExecuteSQLRecord processor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for now, Users cannot add new properties to **`ExecuteSQL*`** processors.

Below are the ways you can try

1. Using **`GenerateFlowFile`** processor

   - Add `schema.name` attribute with some value.

**Flow:**

```
1.GenerateFlowFile //add schema.name attribute with value.
2.ExecuteSQLRecord
2.PutFile
```

**(or)**

2. By `hard code` **`schema.name`** value in **RecordWriter** controller service. in this case you don't need GenerateFlowFile processor.

**Flow:**

```
1.ExecuteSQLRecord //hardcode schema.name property value
2.PutFile
```

Comment: You might also be able to set the value for `schema.name` as a Process Group variable, if the value is to remain the same for all components in that Process Group.